# Attempting to Create Code to transfer from a source list to prefilled documents and then save the iteration in google drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm struggling with the save to pdf section.  I've googled and all of the answers I've found are above my knowledge to copy.  The save to pdf section is the very last bit of code.  I've tried ChatGPT as well, but it seems to struggle with this.  Ultimately, I'd prefer it to print than save, but that isn't something that happens from what I can tell.

As far as I can tell, the rest of the code works.  I did take out the IDs though.  I've tried several different variations on how to make it work.  What I feel like will work is the little bit of code on the save as portion below.  The rest of the code in the example I saw is way above my ability though.

There are comment sections labeling what I'm attempting to do in each area.  I'm sure excel would be easier to work with, but I'm trying to get into google sheets because it seems easier to share data among coworkers.

```
function copyDataAndSaveAsPDF() {
  // Get the source and destination sheets
  var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('errorsList');
  var conductSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('conductError');
  var docSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('docError');
  var medSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('medError');
  
  // Get the data range from the source sheet
  var dataRange = sourceSheet.getDataRange();
  
  // Get the values in the data range
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  
  // Loop through each row in the data
  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) { // Start from 1 to skip header row
    // Extract data from the source sheet
    var column1Data = data[i][0]; // Replace with the appropriate column index
    var column2Data = data[i][1]; // Replace with the appropriate column index
    // ... Continue extracting data for other columns as needed
    var column3Data = data[i][2];
    var column4Data = data[i][3];
    var column5Data = data[i][4];

    // Determine the destination sheet based on the 'type' value
    var destSheet;
    var type = column3Data;
    if (type === 'Conduct') {
      destSheet = conductSheet;
    } else if (type === 'Documentation') {
      destSheet = docSheet;
    } else if (type === 'Medication') {
      destSheet = medSheet;
    }
    if (destSheet === conductSheet) {
      destSheet.getRange(3,2).setValue(column1Data);
      destSheet.getRange(3,5).setValue(column2Data);
      destSheet.getRange(5,2).setValue(column4Data);
      destSheet.getRange(12,2).setValue(column5Data);
    } else if (destSheet === docSheet) {
      destSheet.getRange(3,2).setValue(column1Data);
      destSheet.getRange(3,5).setValue(column2Data);
      destSheet.getRange(5,3).setValue(column4Data);
      destSheet.getRange(30,2).setValue(column5Data);
    } else if (destSheet === medSheet) {
      destSheet.getRange(3,2).setValue(column1Data);
      destSheet.getRange(3,5).setValue(column2Data);
      destSheet.getRange(5,2).setValue(column4Data);
      destSheet.getRange(13,2).setValue(column4Data);
      destSheet.getRange(28,2).setValue(column5Data);
    }
    
      // Save the destination sheet as a PDF with a custom name
      var pdfName = column1Data + '.' + column2Data + '.' + column3Data; // Customize the naming convention

      var pdf = docurl.getBlobl().setName().getAs('application/pdf');
          var fid = '';
        var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(fid);
        folder.createFile(pdf);
  }
}
```

Comment: There is typo: instead of  `getBlobl()` it should be `getBlob()` but `docurl` was not declared. You might have to take some steps back to spend some time learning the basics of JavaScript. You should understand variable declaration and method chaining in JavaScript at least enough to be able to read the code that ChatGPT is giving to you and the code that you are finding on the Web.

Answer (score 0):

### SUGGESTION

You can refer to this **sample script for your reference** on how to save the file as a PDF:

```
function saveAsPDF() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ssblob = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getAs('application/pdf');
  // Add the PDF extension
  ssblob.setName(ss.getName() + ".pdf");
  var file = DriveApp.createFile(ssblob);
  // get the file's URL
  console.log('Your PDF file is available at ' + file.getUrl());
}
```

Comment: Let me know if this answers your question, or if there are some clarifications needed so that I can adjust my answer accordingly.